# @font-face : converting and displaying a font (CityBlueprint)

Tags: html, css, fonts, font-face

I try to embed a font coming from http://fr.fontstock.net/8826/cityblueprint.html.
First, I convert the font through http://convertfonts.com

Then I insert the css code :

```
@font-face {
   font-family: 'cityblueprint';
   src: url('cityblueprint.eot');
   src: url('cityblueprint.svg#cityblueprint') format('svg'),
        url('cityblueprint.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
        url('cityblueprint.woff') format('woff'),
        url('cityblueprint.ttf') format('truetype');
   font-weight: normal;
   font-style: normal;
}

body {
    font-family: 'cityblueprint';
}
```

But it doesn't work in any browser.

I do the same thing with three random fonts from fontstock and these work perfect.

I don't understand what happened with that "CityBlueprint" font.

Comment: Can you show the line where you call the font? also make sure the font is in the right folder

Comment: With another font in the same folder, it works perfectly

Comment: I tried converting the font using FontSquirrel and I got the error "The file cityblueprint.ttf is blacklisted by the Generator. Webfonts from other distributors cannot be regenerated." Maybe this has something to do with it.

Comment: It may be a clue. I try to convert with one of my working font on FontSquirrel (no blacklisted message) and it works.

Comment: I found the font from a different site and I converted it with convertfonts.com and it's working. Try downloading and converting this one: http://font.downloadatoz.com/download,111098,cityblueprint-for-mac.html

Comment: I try your website with the conversion but it doesn't work.

Comment: I get the font from another website but it doesn't work. Could you please post a working example ?