# Cannot connect a font for HTML page

Tags: html, css, fonts

I need to include Gurmukhi.ttf font which was provided to me. I tried to find answer to my question but found something like this [@font-face : converting and displaying a font (CityBlueprint)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20553641/font-face-converting-and-displaying-a-font-cityblueprint)  but no solution.
At first I tred to generate the font on this site

http://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator

but got the following error "The file gurmukhi.ttf is blacklisted by the Generator. Webfonts from other distributors cannot be regenerated."

Then I used 
http://www.font2web.com/

It generated the required data package and I included fonts, how it was shown in demo.html. But nothing happened. By default the browser uses its own fonts, and Gurmukhi are ignored. Interesting thing is that font in demo.html is also ignored by browsers.

Then I was provided another font type Optima.ttc. I have converted it to ttf format.

http://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator

"Linotype has requested that their font Optima Regular be blacklisted by the Generator. You will not be able to convert this font."

http://www.font2web.com/ 
Here I only got 2 files and in info.html there was the following:

> Sorry, the vendor of Optima nova Regular doesn't allow us to convert this font

But click here to use the Optima nova Regular web font for free

Tip: Click on the purple Sign Up for Free! button and then click on the FREE PLAN link

As I understand both of these files are not free?

Comment: Most/if not all Commercial fonts will be blocked from these services, and you need to pay for the actual font file, and a license to use it on the web.

Answer (score 0):

This are commercial fonts and you need to purchase atleast the web license in order to use them legally (altough you could always make the .ttf conversion yourself locally without using web generators and avoid the blacklisted check, but this is still not a legal solution and the font is still subject to copyrights).

If you don't have the budget to spend on font license, you could always use a free alternative to Optima Nova - there are similar typefaces available for free - try to search for free alternatives that could suit your design (mind that the alternative font may not be of the same quality and may not support as many glyphs).

Comment: How much are these fonts?

Comment: @LucyWeatherford Depends on which you want to use - check the foundry website for information about licensing for the font you choose.